# WiFi braodcastReceiver cause the App to crash

Tags: android, broadcastreceiver, android-wifi

To learn how the `broadCastReceivers` works, i created small examples and followed the dcumentation.
when I created the `mBroadCastReceiver_0` shown below, the App wored fine, but when I added the second `broadCastReceiver` `mBroadCastReceiver_1`, the App crashed and the `logcat` generated the below errors. Can any one please tel me what is wrng with the code?

**Code**:

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

    SetUpAllViews(R.layout.activity_main);  

    this.registerReceiver(this.mBroadCastReceiver_0, new IntentFilter(WifiManager.WIFI_STATE_CHANGED_ACTION));

    ConnectWiFi();

    this.registerReceiver(this.mBroadCastReceiver_1, new IntentFilter(WifiManager.WIFI_STATE_CHANGED_ACTION));
    ....
    ....
    ....
    private BroadcastReceiver  mBroadCastReceiver_0 = new BroadcastReceiver() {
    @Override
    public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        int extraWiFiState = intent.getIntExtra(WifiManager.EXTRA_WIFI_STATE,   
    WifiManager.WIFI_STATE_UNKNOWN);

        switch (extraWiFiState) {
        case WifiManager.WIFI_STATE_ENABLING: setText(R.id.tv_conn_status, "Enabling..."); break;
        case WifiManager.WIFI_STATE_ENABLED: setText(R.id.tv_conn_status, "Enabled"); break;
        case WifiManager.WIFI_STATE_DISABLING: setText(R.id.tv_conn_status, "Disabling..."); break;
        case WifiManager.WIFI_STATE_DISABLED: setText(R.id.tv_conn_status, "Disabled"); break;
        case WifiManager.WIFI_STATE_UNKNOWN: setText(R.id.tv_conn_status, "Unkown_WiFi_State"); break;
        }
    }
};

private BroadcastReceiver mBroadCastReceiver_1 = new BroadcastReceiver() {

    @Override
    public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        WifiInfo wifiInfo = intent.getParcelableExtra(WifiManager.EXTRA_WIFI_INFO);
        int linkSpeed = wifiInfo.getLinkSpeed();
        setText(R.id.tv_conn_lspeed, "LinkSpeed: "+linkSpeed);
    }
};
```

**LogCat**:

```
11-07 19:31:53.429: E/AndroidRuntime(6957): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
11-07 19:31:53.429: E/AndroidRuntime(6957): Process: com.example.wifi_socket_00, PID: 6957
11-07 19:31:53.429: E/AndroidRuntime(6957): java.lang.RuntimeException: Error receiving broadcast 
Intent { act=android.net.wifi.WIFI_STATE_CHANGED flg=0x4000010 (has extras) } in   
com.example.wifi_socket_00.MainActivity$2@4302df40
11-07 19:31:53.429: E/AndroidRuntime(6957):     at   
android.app.LoadedApk$ReceiverDispatcher$Args.run(LoadedApk.java:782)
11-07 19:31:53.429: E/AndroidRuntime(6957):     at   
com.example.wifi_socket_00.MainActivity$2.onReceive(MainActivity.java:78)
```

Comment: I'd guess something was null either the intent or the intent had no extras.  This would be pretty easy to debug you can set a breakpoint and make sure nothing is null.  Good Luck

Comment: @danny117  i have checked of the intent is null or not, and i also checked if the intent has the extras i am lookinf for, and the result is, the intent is not null and has that extras